# Forcing right alignment with floated elements not possible when word wrapping

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```
<div id="wrap" style="width:300px">
    <ul style="float:right">
        <li style="float:left">first</li>
        <li style="float:left">second</li>
        <li style="float:left">third</li>
        <li style="float:left">and the fourth is longer than the others</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xLq1hfby/

I want the `<li>`s to align to the right like this:

```
                  [first] [second] [third]
[and the fourth is longer than the others]
```

However, since the last element causes a word wrap, it just looks like this:

```
[first] [second] [third]
[and the fourth is longer than the others]
```

When the last `<li>` is removed, they align like I want them to, like this:

```
                  [first] [second] [third]
```

How can I get them to align to the right even when word wrapping?

Please keep in mind:

- I can't use `display:inline-block` on the `<li>`s because I need vertical margins.
- I can't use `float:right` on the `<li>`s because this reverses their order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox with the following settings (note: no float, 'justify-content: flex-end;' aligns the items to the right.):

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  margin-right: auto;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  margin:4px;
}
```

Here is a fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0o93dvrp/

Comment: Just perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a none-flexbox version (inline block + text align right trick)
https://jsfiddle.net/sxLk5mt2/

```
/* toggle the following line: */
/* #longest {display:none;} */

#wrap {
  background:yellow;
  width:300px;
}

ul {
  float:right;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  /* float:left; */
  display: inline-block;
  margin:4px;
}
```